# No error events in Firebase onValue stream

Tags: firebase, dart

I'm new to Dart and Firebase, but after playing a little bit with them I've stumbled upon the following problem:

I've created a test firebase app with the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "privateTestData": {
        ".write": "false",
        ".read": "auth.uid !== null && auth.uid == $uid"
    },
    "publicTestData": {
        ".write": false,
        ".read": true
    }
  }
}
```

Now when I read publicTestData, everything is ok. But when I try to read privateTestData (not being authenticated) I expect to receive some security error or something like this, but errorHandler is never called.

My code:

```
FB.Firebase testFBReference;

valueHandler(FB.Event event) {
    var value = event.snapshot.val();
    print("Value: '$value'.");
}

errorHandler(error) {
    print("Some error.");
}

doneHandler() {
    print("Done.");
}

void initializeFBReference() {
    testFBReference = new FB.Firebase("https://test.firebaseio.com/privateTestData");
    testFBReference.onValue.listen(valueHandler, onError: errorHandler, onDone: doneHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important item here is that you also don't get to read the value.  You'll have to check the authentication yourself or leverage Firebase.getAuth() (for v2).

The errorHandle on listen is more for errors regarding that specific listener (mainly invalid object/path) and not for authentication.